# Para crear una mini red social, es necesario saber POO?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, css3, mysqli

Hablando de PHP.

Es necesario conocer lo que es la utilización de la programación orientada a objeto.

¿Qué tan importante es?

> Me facilita las cosas.

Comment: Sí, por jerarquizar , abstraer, mantener y escalar

Comment: Esta pregunta se basa mucho en opiniones. Quizás tu pregunta pueda ser más específica y orientarse a qué beneficios tienes al utilizar este paradigma al momento de implementar tu solución. Y en realidad, un paradigma de programación como POO, PF u otro no define el producto que vayas a generar, eso lo decides tú.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitivamente es necesario conocer POO para una red social de cualquier otra forma tendrías que hacer una maraña de queries en tu base de datos que no seria mantenible.
y no solo necesitas POO para PHP sino que vas a necesitar un ORM para tu base de datos, para hacer relaciones de manera mas clara.

Te recomiendo que utilices un Framework que te ofrezca todo esto, mi recomendación seria Laravel, la curva de aprendizaje no es tan pronunciada y Eloquent, el ORM de laravel te va a ayudar muchísimo a generar relaciones entre usuarios.

Lo ultimo que quiero es desanimarte, pero creo que debes analizar la viabilidad de realizar una pequeña Red Social, ya que es muchísimo trabajo y necesitas muchas habilidades y tiempo para un buen resultado. 
El lado positivo es que si te aventuras a este proyecto, vas a aprender muchísimo y al final tendrás un gran proyecto que te respaldara como programador. 
El lado negativo es que un proyecto tan grande puede resultar frustrante en la mayoría de las ocaciones incluso para programadores experimentados, yo te recomendaría empezar con cosas mas pequeñas para ganar experiencia.

Comment: En realidad soy novato en PHP.Y si quiero entrarle auna red social,no es porque la quiero y punto asi por asi.Si no mas bien es que esto me ayuda a ganar conocimientos. Por ejemplo, Están lo que es registros de usuarios, login, sesiones,conexiones al servidor, validación de campos(PHP y también JQuery),entonces me propuse a eso ya que cosas como estas que están incluidas en redes sociales me sirven para otros proyectos. No se si entiendas mi punto.

Comment: Completamente, por eso te comentaba que no quería desanimarte, y si quieres aventarte a algo grande, adelante, pero no te presiones y no le dediques todo tu tiempo, necesitas pequeños proyectos terminados, para ir ganando los conocimientos que necesitas para poder completar una red social.

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo. Lo hare.